# Does my PC use less electricity, if I close files rather than keeping them minimized?

Tags: power

I'm using a Windows 10 laptop. This question assumes that I'm plugged in, and not just relying on battery power. I'd surmise that electricity usage would slacken merely a little, and I wouldn't save much money?

E.g. compare just Firefox with Firefox and Outlook running (with Outlook minimized).

Answer (score 2):

If, as implied by your question, you are just considering Outlook closed vs minimised then the answer would be that in the minimised state it would be periodically checking for email and processing wake events for alerts and notifications.

Therefore it will be using a small amount of power.

How much is difficult to quantify and depends on how often it checks for new email, how long it spends waiting on email server responses, how fast your internet connection is,whether you are connected via wifi or ethernet, how large the emails downloaded are and so on.

With it closed then there is obviously no power drain as it is closed and therefore not doing anything.

For programs in general you will have to consider what the program *does* while minimised versus how much it will have to do when you finally start it back up. It will still have to do all those downloads, but potentially one short burst may be more cost effective than a lot of small checks.

It is up to you to figure out whether a small cost of power while minimised is worth the convenience of getting email and notifications sooner rather than when you remember to launch the application.

Comment: If the OP has no near-term need for the app, they would close it.  So comparing to it being minimized implies that they would otherwise need to reload it in a foreseeable time.  In that case, they would need to compare it to the power needed to reload it.  So it's like the argument about whether you should turn off the lights vs. how soon you will need them again.  :-)

Comment: @fixer1234 that is a very good point. It's a bit like these stop-start engines in cars, they stop when you get to traffic lights but if you stop literally for 1 second before starting again then they may have completely wasted any savings that could have been made. I've edited my answer.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly you are wondering if keeping an application open (minimized) when you are not actively using it is more energy efficient than opening the program when you need it and closing it when you don't.
This will vary greatly from program to program and depends on your particular way of working with the programs and even on the exact details of your hardware and Operating System.
It is simply impossible to give an exact answer because there are to many variables involved.

But in general:
Opening a program (and closing it) burns energy. For most programs a lot more than having it idling in the background. So it probably doesn't make any significant difference in the long run.

If you really want to know if it helps in your particular case you just have to try it for a couple of days and see if your battery life improves. (I doubt if you can notice a difference, but in your specific case it may be beneficial.)

Answer (score 0):

A PC's contribution to electricity bills is primarily caused by the amount of power being drawn. For example, lets take 2 PC's.

The first PC is going to be IDLE for 24 hours.

The second PC is going to be running at 100% utilization for 24 hours.

So which one will use the most? The second PC. It will be drawing constant power to supply enough to allow the PC to run at 100%. Meanwhile, the other PC will not be drawing as much power because it doesn't need to.

In regards to your question, firefox can use a lot of RAM. In theory, closing this down could save on your electricity bills, but i would expect it to have a huge impact.

So yes, closing programs *CAN* reduce your electricity consumption, but it wouldn't have a huge impact unless they draw a lot of power.